# File read error on large files and checkdisk fails. Does my HDD needs replacement?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I've been experiencing file read issues on several large files (>3 GB) on my Windows 10 system lately that are on one particular disk (regular HDD, not SSD).
The easiest reproduction is to copy such file to another disk. Then when the copy is half way, it stops (disk I/O hangs at 100%) and after a minute Windows let's me know it has failed because of a read error.

It does not happen with all large files...

I tried checking this disk with `chkdsk` and it also fails because of read failures. Here is the chkdsk report from my event viewer:

```
Chkdsk was executed in scan mode on a volume snapshot.  

Checking file system on E:
Volume label is Data2.

Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...

  969216 file records processed.                                                         File verification completed.

  208 large file records processed.                                                                                                                           
  0 bad file records processed.                                      
Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...

  2599 reparse records processed.                                                                                                                              
  1266028 index entries processed.                                                        Index verification completed.

  2599 reparse records processed.                                       
Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
Security descriptor verification completed.

  148407 data files processed.                                            CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8deacfc000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead0b000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead0c000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead0e000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead0f000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead0f000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead10000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead10000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead11000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead12000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead13000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead13000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead14000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead1c000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead1d000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead1d000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead1e000 for 0x10000 bytes.
Read failure with status 0xc000009c at offset 0x8dead2c000 for 0x1000 bytes.
Usn Journal verification completed.
Read failure with status 0xc0000483 at offset 0xba594000 for 0x10000 bytes.
A disk read error occurredc0000483

----------------------------------------------------------------------


Stage 1: Examining basic file system structure ...

Stage 2: Examining file name linkage ...

Stage 3: Examining security descriptors ...
An unspecified error occurred (6c6f6766696c652e 2a9).
```

My fear is that the hard drive is broken (at least partially). Can anyone confirm my fear or point me towards a possible solution?

Comment: Quickest & safest would be to just throw out the drive & recover from backup to a new one. Did you check the SMART status?

Comment: Didn't know about SMART, but did some checking. Windows says OK, but also checked with CrystalDiskInfo which says "Caution" as health status for the disk. I will get a replacement and try to safe as much as possible. Thanks!